# Unable to Set DropDownlist with pre-selected value

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, razorengine

Unable to populate dropdonwlist with pre-selected value.Populating with pre-selected value works with viewbag method.However when i am trying the same with a Model based method i find no luck.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int?id)
{
    Job_ClientVM Vm = new Job_ClientVM();
    Vm.Job_Info = Get_jobdetails(id);
    //4 is desired pre-selected ID value     
    Vm.Recruiters = new SelectList(db.Recruiter_Info.ToList(), "Id", 
    "Recruiter_Name",4);
}
```

**Here is my View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.SelectedRecruiterID, Model.Recruiters, "Assign Recruiter", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of `SelectedRecruiterID` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int?id)
{
    Job_ClientVM Vm = new Job_ClientVM();
    Vm.Job_Info = Get_jobdetails(id);    
    Vm.Recruiters = new SelectList(db.Recruiter_Info.ToList(), "Id", "Recruiter_Name");
    // Set the value of SelectedRecruiterID
    Vm.SelectedRecruiterID = 4;
    // Pass the model to the view
    return View(Vm);
}
```

Note that setting the Selected property (the 4th parameter) in the `SelectList` constructor is pointless - its ignored when binding to a model property (internally the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the `Selected` property based on the value of the property.

Comment: Your solution is working but  When i am trying to assign Vm.SelectedRecruiterID=Vm.Job_Info.Recruiter_ID;
 i am facing error cannot convert type int? to int type cast missing. Any idea on how to proceeed

Comment: I do not know what your models are or what types `SelectedRecruiterID` and `Job_Info.Recruiter_ID` are but clearly they are different. Best guess without seeing your models is `Vm.SelectedRecruiterID = Vm.Job_Info.Recruiter_ID.GetValueOrDefault();`

Comment: I fixed the issue by changing SelectedRecruiterID  to 
"  public Nullable<int> SelectedRecruiterID { get; set; }"

I wanted to ask you if you have any material for good practices on dropdown lists . Thank you

Comment: Since its a view model it should be nullable anyway (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688968/what-does-it-mean-for-a-property-to-be-required-and-nullable/43689575#43689575) for an explanation). What your doing - creating a view model and including a property for the `SelectList` and using the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()` method is the best practice :). Just remember to repopulate the `Recruiters` property in the POST method if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid.