# how to get unique id from radiobuttonfor in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, radiobuttonfor

I have a below model

```
public class category
{
    [Key]
    public long category_id { get; set; }
    public string category_desc { get; set; }
    public long? client_id { get; set; }
    public long? display_sno { get; set; }
}
```

controller passing the model to view

```
public ActionResult category(long? client_id)
{
    var category_type = db.category.Where(m => m.client_id == null).ToList();
    if(client_id == 10)
    {
        category_type = db.category.Where(m => m.client_id == client_id).ToList();
    }
    return View(category_type);
}
```

In view populating the radion button

```
@foreach (var item in Model)                                                 
{ 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.display_sno)<text>.</text> &nbsp;
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.category_id, item.category_id, new { id=item.category_id})@item.category_desc
}
```

post Method

```
public ActionResult Category(category g)
{

}
```

In post method `g` is coming as `null`.
What I am missing here?

Comment: Your radio button does not make sense. You need a group of radio buttons bound to the same property with different values. Its no clear what your wanting to do with this code

Comment: @StephenMuecke category_id will be unique for each radiobutton and while posting back need to get the selected category_id

Comment: Yes but for that your need a model with a property (lets say `public long category_id { get; set; }`) and the another property which is a collection containing the values for each radio button (lets say `public IEnumerable<int> Values { get; set; }` and then its `foreach (var item in Model.Values { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.category_id, item) }`

Comment: Which assuming `Values` is `[1,2,3,4]` would generate `<input type="radio" name="category_id" value="1">` (and `value="2"` etc). And when you submit, if you selected the 2nd radio button, the the value of `category_id` would be `2`

Comment: @StephenMuecke values are not 1,2,3... category_id is random numbers..

Comment: I know :) - its just an example. You model needs a property to bind to and a property which is a collection of something that provides the values to use for the radio buttons.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i understood but how to get IEnumerable of category_id is confusing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159110/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-sachu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding how radio buttons work. They are for binding one of many options to a single property, in the same way a dropdownlist works. Your code is generating radio buttons that bind to itself. And if you inspect the html you will see that it generates `name="item.category_id"` which would not bind to your model anyway (that would only bind to a model containing a complex object named `Item` which contained a property named `category_id`).

Assuming you have a model for a `Product` which contained a property for its `Category`, and you wanted to assign one of the values of your `category` table to the `Category` property, then your view models would look like

```
public class ProductVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a category")]
    public int? Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryVM> CategoryOptions { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Note the use of a nullable property for `Category` is explained in [What does it mean for a property to be [Required] and nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688968/what-does-it-mean-for-a-property-to-be-required-and-nullable/43689575#43689575)

Then the controller methods (for a Create view) would look like

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ProductVM model = new ProductVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}
public ActionResult Create(ProductVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid())
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    .... // Initialize your Product data model, set its properties based on the view model
    // Save and redirect
}
private void ConfigureViewModel(ProductVM model)
{
    model.CategoryOptions = db.categories.Select(x => new CategoryVM
    {
        ID = x.category_id,
        Name = x.category_desc
    });
}
```

Then the view would be

```
@model ProductVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Category)
    foreach(var category in Model.CategoryOptions)
    {
        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Category, category.ID, new { id = "" })
            <span>@category.Name</span>
        </label>
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)
    <input type="submit" .... />
}
```

Note that the `new { id = "" }` is removing the `id` attribute which would otherwise be invalid html because of duplicates.