# Remove blank entry from EnumDropDownListFor(...)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, html-helper

I found a few S.O. posts regarding this problem, but none of the accepted answers worked for me.  I am using an `enum` to create an `EnumDropDownListFor` and it's working, but I do not want a blank entry at the top of the drop-down.  I want the user to be forced to accept one of the items from the `enum`.  Code follows:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, new { @class = "input-block-level " + Model.FooThingType, autocomplete = "off", style = "width: 100px;" })
```

Note on the above, I have tried several variants of this based on the accepted answers in other S.O. posts, including adding and removing a variety of arguments in the `EnumDropDownListFor(...)` call.  This results only in compile time errors, mostly "no version of EnumDropDownListFor() takes *n* arguments" errors.  E.g.:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, null, new { @class = "input-block-level " + Model.FooThingType, autocomplete = "off", style = "width: 100px;" })
```

... or ...

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, "whatever", new { @class = "input-block-level " + Model.FooThingType, autocomplete = "off", style = "width: 100px;" })
```

The enum itself:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    [Description("Thingie")]
    Thingie,

    [Description("AnotherThingie")]
    AnotherThingie,

    [Description("LastThingie")]
    LastThingie
}
```

I also tried this, but it made no difference:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    [Description("Thingie")]
    Thingie = 0,

    [Description("AnotherThingie")]
    AnotherThingie = 1,

    [Description("LastThingie")]
    LastThingie = 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown you model, but clearly your property is nullable, i.e.

```
public SomeEnum? Foo { get; set }
```

which allows `null` values, therefore the `EnumDropDownListFor()` method generates a `null` option so that it can be selected.

You can either make the property not nullable (which will remove the `null` option)

```
public SomeEnum Foo { get; set }
```

or better, leave it nullable and add the `[Required]` attribute to force the user to make a selection which protects against under-posting attacks (refer [What does it mean for a property to be [Required] and nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688968/what-does-it-mean-for-a-property-to-be-required-and-nullable/43689575#43689575) for a detailed explanation)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a ... ")]
public SomeEnum Foo { get; set }
```

and in the view add

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, new { ... })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Foo)
```