# How return null for an empty combo box instead of 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I have two linked combo, Year and Week.

Im sending the list of year and empty data set for week to the View

```
ViewBag.YearID = new SelectList(db.years, "YearID", "Name");
ViewBag.WeekID = new SelectList(db.week_list.Where(x => x.Name == ""), "WeekID", "Name");
```

In the View I have

```
@Html.DropDownList("YearID", null, "Seleccione Año", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("WeekID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Right now when start Year have a help message `Select Year` without value.

```
<select class="form-control" id="YearID" name="YearID">
    <option value="">Seleccione Año</option>
    <option value="7">2016</option>
    <option value="8">2017</option>
    <option value="9">2018</option>
</select>
```

So because not year has been selected I pass an empty list for weeks and result on this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="WeekID" name="WeekID">
</select>
```

**Starting State:**

[image]

The problem is when I hit `Create` button to send the form. The action controller get the wrong value for WeekID

```
 YearID = null  -- as I espect
 WeekID = 0     -- dont know why. I expect null
```

Then the validation show Year is required, but doesnt show anything for Week because already received 0

**Validation State:**

[image]

Comment: The selection of Year dropdown has nothing to do with your Week dropdown.  Your current code `db.week_list.Where(x => x.Name == "")` is returning 0 results, hence the razor view renders an empty SELECT element. Remove the where clause from the linq expression and see what happens.

Comment: You need to make both properties nullable and with the `[Required]` attribute. And that is possibly the worst way to generate you `<select>` elements. Use a view model with `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties and strongly bind to your model using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectYear, Model.YearList, "Please select", new { ... })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Both are already `[Required]` but dont allow null, because they are Required. The problem isnt with the Year, is with the Week dropdown. If I create an empty list return value 0 when should return NULL

Comment: It need to be nullable and `[Required]`! When you submit the form, no value is posted for `Week` therefore its set to the default (i.e. `0` for an `int`). Refer also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688968/what-does-it-mean-for-a-property-to-be-required-and-nullable/43689575#43689575)

Comment: @Shyju There is a javascript code populating Week when Year change. But when page load and no year has been selected the Weeks is empty

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can try. But I dont understand why have different behaviour.  Right now both are required and dont allow null, and as you can see the behaviour is different. Because by default the Year has `<option value="">Seleccione Año</option>` and that option return null But because Week have empty list return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the property nullable and add the `[Required]` attribute.

When you submit your form, the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes your model, and at that point, the value of `YearID` and `WeekID` are both `0` (the default value for `int`)

The name/value pairs are then read from the request. Because there is a `name/value` pair for `YearID` which is `null`, the `DefaultModelBinder` attempts to set `YearID = null` which fails, and a `ModelState` error is added for `YearID` (the `actualValue` of the property is `0` and the `attemptedValue` is `null`)

Because the dropdownlist for `WeekID` does not contain any `<option>` elements, no `name/value` pair is sent in the request, so no attempt is made to set the value, and the value of `WeekID` remains a `0`. Because `0` is valid for `int`, there is no `ModelState` error for `WeekID`, which is why no error message is displayed.

In addition, your use of `DropDownList()` means that no matter what you select in the first dropdownlist, when you return the view, the first option (`Seleccione Año`) will be selected (what the user previously selected is lost)

You are editing data so you should always be using a view model which will include

```
public class YourVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public int? SelectedYear { get; set; } // nullable
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public int? SelectedWeek { get; set; } // nullable
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YearList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WeekList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view, strongly bind to your model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, Model.YearList, "Seleccione Año", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidatinMessageFor(m => m.SelectedYear)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedWeek, Model.WeekList, "Seleccione Año", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidatinMessageFor(m => m.SelectedWeek)
```

Comment: The nullable property work perfect. The key was understand the model is initialize with the default values. But I can't use the strongly bind for Week because that is a cascade combo. So depend on what you have selected from Year. Unless there is a way to do that without javascript? Can you encapsulate a method in YourVM class to return the filter IEnumerable for Weeks? Right now Im using  getJson from JQuery

Comment: Yes you can, and absolutely should use the strongly bound `HtmlHelper` methods (always). And if you want to understand how to generate cascading dropdownlists, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Is me or that .Net fiddle have issue with the scroll botton of the mouse?

Comment: What issue are you having with the mouse?

Comment: I try to scroll down but jump back up. Have to use arrow instead

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: Thanks for the sample anyway that is just what I need. There is a minor issue not sure if can be solved. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm51Q.png  if you press save with everything empty. You get all the error message. If you start filling the combos the error go away. But if you deselect the combo the error is back, but only for that combo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169391/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Comment: Hey stephen, could you take a look to the fiddle? Or should I start a new question to try to get help about it?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the answer you asked but the pattern I use to handle the dependent control issue is to show the second only after the first is valid. From experience, this pattern saves me a lot of headaches.

Comment: The visibility is irrelevant, the problem is an empty list return 0 instead of null.