# C# - ModelState.IsValid is false when not providing values for NON-REQUIRED fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project.
This project has the `HomeController` with the action `Insert`.
`Insert()` takes in model `Model`.

The problem is that when submitting the form on the client side `ModelState.IsValid` is `false` when I don't fill in the non-required field `ReportedCount`.

When leaving the field blank, the code automatically picks it up as 0 because it is an int. I've tried manipulating this to a different number during debug but `ModelState.IsValid` does not change.
I know that the error happens just with the `ReportedCount` field. When I go into `ModelState` during debug, the only key that has the error is `ReportedCount`. So, of course I go ahead and re-submit the form with the field populated with a number and in that case it is accepted (IsValid = true).

Here is the model:

```
public class Model
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ID field is required.")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 100000, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Number")]
    public int ReportedCount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller action:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(Model model)
    {
        bool insert = false;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            insert = Service.Insert(model);
        }

        // If information was inserted properly. 
        if (insert == true)
        {
            TempData["message"] = "<b>Input successful :</b> Data entered for id " + model.ID;
            TempData["success"] = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            // System error has priority to be displayed first.
            if (DatabaseError != null)
            {

                TempData["message"] = DatabaseError;
                TempData["success"] = "false";
            }
            else 
            {
                // Create element showing Model errors.
                string message = "";
                message = message + "<b>There was an error inserting your data.</b> <ul>";

                foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
                    {
                        message = message + "<li>" + error.ErrorMessage + "</li>";
                    }
                }

                message = message + DatabaseError + "</ul>";

                TempData["message"] = message;
                TempData["success"] = "false";
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And the html code for the inputs (View):

```
<html>
    <div class='form-group required'>
        <label class='control-label'>ID</label>
        <select name="ID" class='form-control required' id="DD_ID" required>
            <option value="">Select ID</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
            <label class='control-label'>Reported Count</label>
            <input class='form-control' type='number' name="ReportedCount">
    </div>
    <div class='form-row'>
            <input class='form-control' id='username' type='hidden' name="UserName" value="@(ViewBag.UserName)" />
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: And the error message...?

Comment: `RangeAttribute` provides `Minimum` and `Maximum` properties.  In your case `0` to `100,000`.  Last I looked, `null` does not fall within this range.

Comment: also, how do you expect an `int` to hold a `null` ?

Comment: System picks up null as 0 already. If tried removing the range also but its still not working. That makes sense because it was never giving me the Range error message of ErrorMessage = "Invalid Number". I just get a "The Reported Count field is required" message.

Comment: I needed to change the datatype from int to int? thanks for the link!

Comment: Refer also [What does it mean for a property to be Required and nullable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688968/what-does-it-mean-for-a-property-to-be-required-and-nullable/43689575#43689575)